# array name not display in json output while using node

Tags: android, node.js, spinner

**My Result: Node Output**

> Following result from nodejs using api to get all item to display the anddroid spinner

```
[
  { "item": "WATER" },
  { "item": "DFG" },
  { "item": "2InchPipe" },
  { "item": "5InchPipe" }
]
```

**My Code: Node Code**

> This is my nodejs code to get item from MSSQL

```
//GET ITEM DROP DOWN INFO
app.get("/api/user/spinner", function(req , res){
  var query = "select item from ItemSetting_tbl ";
  executeQuery (res, sendname);
});`
```

**My Expectation: Node Output**

> I want to result with array name

```
{
  "Spinner": [
    { "item": "WATER" },
    { "item": "DFG" },
    { "item": "2InchPipe" },
    { "item": "5InchPipe" }
  ]
}
```

**Finally i got solution using this code**

```
JsonArrayRequest requestQueue = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String country = obj.getString("item");
                            CountryName.add(country);
                            spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CountryName));
                        }

                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }


    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQue(requestQueue );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your result into required JSON like below

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.add("Spinner", result);
```

**object** will be your required json

Comment: thank you. but  i dont know where i need to add this code. because node result does not display json array name. my question is how to get array name for json result.

Comment: You have to add this in your android code where you are getting response

Comment: Finally i got a solution use other concept. Thanks to support